# Creating a Numpy Array from two Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I had a DataFrame called "segments" that looks like the below:

```
ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID  DEST_AIRPORT_ID  FL_COUNT  ORIGIN_INDEX  DEST_INDEX  OUTDEGREE 
 WEIGHT
0  10135  10397  77  119  373  3  0.333333
1  10135  11433  85  119  1375  3  0.333333
```

Using this, I created two Boolean Series objects: One in which I'm storing all the IDs for which the WEIGHT column is not 0 and one in which they are:

```
Zeroes = (segments['WEIGHT'] == 0).groupby(segments['ORIGIN_INDEX']).all()
Non_zeroes = (segments['WEIGHT'] != 0).groupby(segments['ORIGIN_INDEX']).all()
```

I want to do two things (because I'm not sure which this task needs):

- Create a NumPy vector where all "True" values in the Non_zeroes Series are set to the result of 1/4191 (~0.024~) and all "True" values in the Zeroes Series are set to 0 (or the same logic using True and False of one Series) keeping the IDs (e.g. ORIGIN_INDEX 119 0.024%, etc.)
- And I'd also like to create a NumPy vector that is JUST a list of the percentages and zeroes WITHOUT the IDs

EDIT to add extra detail requested!

I tried using a condition as a variable, then using .loc to apply it:

```
cond_array = copied.WEIGHT is not 0
df.loc[cond_array, ID] = 1/4191
```

I tried using from_coo(), toarray(), and DataFrame to convert:

```
pd.Series.sparse.from_coo(P, dense_index=True) 
P.toarray() 
pd.DataFrame(P)
```

Finally, I tried applying logic to the DF instead of the COO Matrix. I THINK this gets close, but it is still failing. I believe it fails because it is not including the 0s (copied is just a DF that's a copy of segments):

```
copied['WEIGHT'] = copied.loc[copied['WEIGHT'] != 0, 'WEIGHT'] = float((1/len(copied))) #0.00023860653
```

The last code passes the first two tests (testing if it's an array and that it sums to 1.0), but fails the last

```
assert np.isclose(x0.max(), 1.0/n_actual, atol=10*n*np.finfo(float).eps), "x0` values seem off..."
```

EDIT 2:
Had the wrong count. It was supposed to be 1/300, not 1/4191. All fixed now, thanks all who took a look :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show us what you have tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you!
Used a condition as a variable, then using .loc to apply it 
`df.loc[cond_array, ID] = 1/4191`

Used from_coo(), toarray(), and DataFrame to convert:
`pd.Series.sparse.from_coo(P, dense_index=True)`
`P.toarray()`
`pd.DataFrame(P)`

Finally, I tried applying logic to the DF instead of the COO Matrix. I THINK this gets close, but it is still failing. I believe it fails because it is not including the 0s (copied is just a DF that's a copy of segments):
`copied['WEIGHT'] = copied.loc[copied['WEIGHT'] != 0, 'WEIGHT'] = float((1/len(copied))) #0.00023860653`

Comment: (Ran out of room!)

The last code passes the first two tests (testing if it's an array and that it sums to 1.0), but fails the last
`----> 5 assert np.isclose(x0.max(), 1.0/n_actual, atol=10*n*np.finfo(float).eps), "`x0` values seem off..."`

Comment: Comments aren't the best place for further clarifications: It would be better to edit your questions.

Comment: Updated! Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out the issue. I'll update the original post, but I was counting the unique values in the wrong column. It was supposed to be 1/300, not 1/4191 -_-